# Integrating a MS Teams call / meeting video stream into a website

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

How do I embed the video of a Teams meeting / call into our own website? I've had a look at the graph API and also the online meeting bots. It seems like this is possible using a meeting bot - assuming that the bot can receive the meeting video and that this video can be streamed onto the website? The website should basically just have a video frame that streams the call video.

Comment: Hi, welcome new user.  You may consider a different channel in Stack Exchange to ask a hypothetical question. If you would like your question answered here, please rephrase your question from a hypothetical, "Is it possible," to a concrete example, "How do I."  To meet the minimal question requirement, please provide a sample Teams video and your code attempt and your output and error message.  Specify your specific web API and security protocols for Teams authentication. You can ask for other tools suggestions, but you would still need to provide one attempt of your own.

Comment: This is currently on our roadmap: [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=2519](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=25197)

Comment: We don't have ETA to share with you.